# Sublime Text 4 with conda env

Tags: python, conda, sublimetext4

I'd like to run python code I'm editing in Sublime Text 4 in a specific conda env.  Questions [Virtualenvs in Sublime Text 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68652617) and [use conda environment in sublime text 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34865717) asked similar questions.  The starting configuration Olgierd Wiśniewski had would serve for me if it worked.  I edited his build code to:

```
{
    "shell_cmd": "C://Users/steve/anaconda3/envs/PY10_2/python.exe -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

saved it to my ST user directory, closed ST and reopened it.  When I selected "Build With" I did not see my new sublime-build.

Would someone please set me straight?

Comment: What did you save it as? Can you copy and paste the exact name of the file?

Comment: It had saved it as a build, ,but not with Python and Python Debug.  I just didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

You should find the new option (your new sublime-build) in `Tools -> Build System` .